# Equivalent to OP_RETURN? Want to write string to be visible on blockchain

Tags: solidity

On the bitcoin blockchain, you can write a string as an OP_RETURN value and then when the block is seen on a block explorer, you see the string.

I want to do the same thing.  I want to write a string to a private Ethereum blockchain.

Can anyone suggest a way?

Another way to ask: how would you propose to a girl on the Ethereum blockchain?

*EDIT: I no longer believe this needs re-opening.  I agree that I literally posted the same question twice.*

Comment: Yes this is a straight duplicate.  I literally posted twice because I forgot that I had posted once.  The answer is to include the data as hex, but view it on the blockchain explorer as ASCII if the explorer has the conversion feature.

Answer (score 1):

You could mine a block and add arbitrary string to extraData field. Or you can put your string to the input data of a transaction.

You can find the description of extraData in the [yellow paper](http://yellowpaper.io):

> extraData: An arbitrary byte array containing
>   data relevant to this block. This must be 32 bytes
>   or fewer; formally Hx.

When using `geth` with `--mine` option you can also set the [extra data](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options):

> --extradata value       Block extra data set by the miner (default = client version)

You can see Extra Data on Etherscan https://etherscan.io/block/4518843

---

You can find the description of the input data in the yellow paper as well:

> data: An unlimited size byte array specifying the
>   input data of the message call, formally Td.

You can set it when [sending a transaction](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction) in JS console in geth inside the transaction object:

> data: String - (optional) Either a byte string containing the associated data of the message, or in the case of a contract-creation transaction, the initialisation code.

Comment: Can you give me something specific?  Like a link to an explanation of what the extraData field is and where it lives?  Or how to change the "input data of a tranasction"?

Comment: @stone212 I added more details.